# Best strategy for multiple choice negative marking and blank penalty

Tags: probability, logic

In a multiple choice question,
There are 4 options.
1 is correct and rewards 5 points.
3 are incorrect and cost 2 points.
Leaving blank costs 1 point anyway.

Is it rational to leave the question blank, even in the case of random guess?

Comment: In terms of expected outcome, both options (leaving it blank and taking a random guess) result in a $-1/4$ point change per question.

Comment: If you have a test where you know in advance that a score above 90% gives an A, and above 75% is a B, etc, then your strategy should also reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's suppose you, absolutely, without question, do not have a *clue* as to how to answer this multiple-choice question. You can do two things:

- You can make the random guess, hoping for the $1/4$ chance at $+5$ points, knowing if you're wrong you get $-2$ points.
- You can leave the question blank, and get $-1$ points. A penalty but not as much, right?

In cases like these, we consider the "expectation" of what you'd earn in the former scenario. It's like, if you were presented with a bunch of such questions, what would you earn on average?

Formally in probability and statistics, we denote this $E(X)$ and consider a space of events $X$ with events $x \in X$ given a value. In this case, our $x$'s are the point gains. $E(X)$ is given by the summation

$$E(X) = \sum_{x \in X} x \cdot P(x)$$

where $P(x)$ is the probability of $x$. This *looks* complicated but it's actually just a weighted sum of each value times how likely it is. In this scenario of our random guess, we have $4$ events: $3$ are $-2$ points with $1/4$ probability each, and $1$ is $+5$ points also at $1/4$ probability. Thus, here,

$$E(X) = \sum_{x \in X} x \cdot P(x) = (-2)\left( \frac{1}{4} \right) + (-2)\left( \frac{1}{4} \right) + (-2)\left( \frac{1}{4} \right) + (5)\left( \frac{1}{4} \right)$$

Calculating this sum, you find

$$E(X) = -\frac{3}{2} + \frac{5}{4} = -\frac{1}{4}$$

So, on average, you would expect to lose $1/4$ of a point for a random guess scenario.

By comparison, you clearly lose $1$ point on average for just leaving it blank.

Therefore, it's more rational to just take a random guess on average, since $-1/4 > -1$.